# Google permissions request conflicts with invocation of google script function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

I have a google sheet that I use as a template, so I make different copies.
In it, I have a button (graphic with associated script) that invokes a function that requires permissions.

> Every time I make a copy and invoke this function for the first time, the authorization request is presented, and the function itself is not executed (which is executed later, once the permissions were granted).

- How can I do so that the necessary permissions are requested and the function is invoked immediately afterwards?
- I am not understanding the invocation sequence.
  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Don't make copies of the function, use the same function repeatedly.

Comment: It should call the function immediately after authorization. Provide execution logs of that first click function invocation

Comment: Hi TheMaster, I would need the permissions to be requested but without interfering with the function call.
When I execute the first click on the button associated with the function, the authorization request interface is displayed, but the invocation of the function is not recorded in the log.
Is there any way to detect by code if the permissions have already been granted ?
Or what can I do so that the permissions are requested and then the function is executed ? (in a single call).
Thank you very much

Comment: @Aurora Could you explain in more detail? When the button is clicked, do you have a red banner at the top saying, something along the lines of "Script running". And what happens after you finish authorization? Is there a page "Authorization successful"?

Comment: @TheMaster, I will try to describe the different steps: 1 - I have a sheet that is used as a template, with a picture associated with a sequence of commands 2- The first time that I open the sheet (generated as a copy of the template), when I click the picture, the authorizations is asked 3- I accept the granting of permissions 4 - when I go to see the log, there is no execution record 5-Then, I click the picture again, the function is executed succesfuly . I would need a way to get the function to run the first time as well. Thanks again !

Comment: it would be useful for me to be able to invoke two functions from the picture. The first one would be an empty function but the first time it is executed it would ask for permissions. Then I call the specific function.

Comment: If not, is there any way to check by code if the permissions have already been granted ? That way you could add an informative message prompting the authorization request.

Comment: Check the last script in > Guide to add-on lifecycle in > the below post's > first link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all new functions or new copies of functions have to be authorized before they can be used.

It's just the way it is.

There is no way around it.

I use the same spreadsheet and many of the same functions in answering questions here at SO.  If I made copies of the spreadsheet container all of the time I would have to authorize them for the first time use every time.

- [Authorization of Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Cooper, thanks your quick response.
My problem is not that the function has to be authorized every time I make a copy, but that in addition to being authorized, it is executed.
Since the authorization screens are presented, but the function does not execute although the invocation.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, normally the authorization has to come from a person or a user and the user has to authorize and the authorization often results in the script not actually executing.

Comment: Thanks again ! Do you know any trick to invoke the function again, once the permissions have been granted ?